# Python SerializeToString and Unmarshal in Go Protobuf

Tags: python, go, protocol-buffers, proto

I need to send a protobuf message from a python to a Go system. In the python side i call `SerializeToString()` and send this string as the body of a http response. In the go side of the project, I call `Unmarshal()` after reading the response body. But I get `proto: cannot parse invalid wire-format data` error while doing so.

Note the other way round, when I send request from Go to Python, then the request marshal in Go and unmarshal in Python work without any issue.

Any ideas? thank you

Comment: What is the output of `SerializeToString()`

Comment: `Unmarshal()` is the right function to use. Unfortunately, more information is needed to debug the issue.

Comment: Hi, have u figured out the solution?

Answer (score -1):

The Python `SerializeToString()` function is a way to create binary-encoded string representations of protobuf messages for e.g. [writing messages to a file](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/pythontutorial#writing-a-message) **but** this is not the way to send messages across the wire.

IIUC you have a Golang client and a Python server?

The Golang client should invoke the service method. Something of the form:

```golang
resp,err := client.SomeMethod(ctx,&pb.SomeMethodRequest{...})
```

The Python server should have an implementation of the service method. Something of the form:

```py
def SomeMethod(self, request, context)
```

> **NOTE** gRPC ensures that `&pb.SomeMethodRequest{...}` passed to `SomeMethod` on the Golang client appears as `request` in the Python server method.

In the client and server you'll be working with Golang types and Python classes (e.g. `pb.SomeMethodRequest`) generated by the `protoc` compiler.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But the python side is a function which runs in OpenFaaS. Still I want to use proto objects inside the python function. So I cant really implement the gRPC - rpc function calls in the python side.

Comment: So you want the Golang client to use regular HTTP with the Python server? If so, the Golang client should simply `ParseFromString` the message body returned by the Python server. See the [Reading a Message](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/pythontutorial#reading-a-message)